# How to handle dependencies in a React version upgrade

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-widgets

I am upgrading an app built with create-react-app to version 17.0.1.  This is my first major upgrade since developing in React.

I have a dependency, for example, of [react-widgets](https://github.com/jquense/react-widgets) version 4.4.11.

In react-widget's devDependencies I see React 16 referenced.

```
"react": "^16.4.1",  
"react-dom": "^16.4.1",
```

There are no peerDependencies listed.

After upgrading my app's react, react-dom, and react-scripts to the latest everything seems to run just fine.

So basically react-widgets was written with React 16 and I am running it with React 17. Is this Ok to do? React 16 and 17 I believe are compatible, but there are differences.

Also, react-widgets is [planning a release of v5 for React 17](https://github.com/jquense/react-widgets/issues/993) which makes this more confusing.

How do you handle dependencies in an upgrade?